# How to Style KeyTips?

Tags: wpf, xaml, styling

I am trying to find the default style for the `KeyTip` control; so I can just change the default values and make my own `KeyTip` Style. But I've had no luck at finding it.

So I've tried this:

```
<Style x:Key="MainKeyTipStyle" TargetType="KeyTipControl" >
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="Effect" Value="{x:Null}"/>
</Style>
```

on a normal button:

```
<Button 
    x:Name="buttonTEST" 
    Content="_TEST" 
    KeyTipService.KeyTip="T" 
    KeyTipService.KeyTipStyle="{StaticResource MainKeyTipStyle}" 
    Click="buttonTEST_Click" 
    />
```

When I run my test and press Alt it ends up looking like this:

[image: KeyTip Style Test]

I would like a solid background color. Not a gradient / fade effect as in my test.
How can I get rid of this default effect?

Any help would be appreciated.

Here are links I've looked at but didn't find helpful:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/e0d1336c-2f95-494b-8c4e-3db8d5ab6761/how-to-style-the-keytip-pop-up-background-in-the-microsoft-ribbon?forum=officegeneral

[MSDN - Key Tip Style](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.keytipservice.keytipstyleproperty?view=netframework-4.8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `Template` property to a custom `ControlTemplate` in your `KeyTipControl` style:

```
<Style x:Key="MainKeyTipStyle" TargetType="KeyTipControl" >
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="Effect" Value="{x:Null}"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="KeyTipControl">
                <Border Name="OuterBorder"
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                        Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Text}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

The default one contains two `Border` elements.

Comment: Thank you :D. This works great. How / Where did you find the default KeyTip Style?

Comment: It's compiled into the `System.Windows.Controls.Ribbon` assembly.

Comment: So by getting the default Ribbon Style, you also get the default KeyTip Style? Am I understanding correctly?

Comment: The `KeyTipControl` style is defined in the same assembly as the other `Ribbon` styles.